# Sed replace hyphen with underscore

Tags: regex, sed, replace

new to regex and have a problem. I want to replace hyphens with underscores in certain places in a file. To simplify things, let's say I want to replace the *first* hyphen. Here's an example "file":

```
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf replace-these-hyphens
```

I want to replace hyphens in all lines found by

```
grep -P "leaf \w+-" file
```

I tried

```
sed -i 's/leaf \(\w+\)-/leaf \1_/g' file
```

but nothing happens (wrong replacement would have been better than nothing). I've tried a few tweaks but still nothing. Again, I'm new to this so I figure the above "should basically work". What's wrong with it, and how do I get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: You're not using the regex extensions which support `\w`.  You need `sed -E` or `sed -r`.

Comment: Like this? `sed -i -E 's/leaf (\w+)\-/leaf \1_/g' file`

Comment: @stevesliva GNU sed understands `\w` just like that. For GNU sed, the only difference between `sed` and `sed -E` (or `sed -r`) is what you have to escape. See also [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions).

Comment: @BenjaminW. you are right.  It's the `+` that you need the extended regex for.  Sorry, I have a hammer and everything looks like a nail.  Right solution, wrong reasoning.

Comment: @stevesliva GNU sed even has an extension to Basic Regular Expressions for that: `\+` is has the same effect as `+` in Extended Regular Expressions. They're really equivalent, apart from quoting; `\(\) \{\} \+ \? \|` in BRE, `() {} + ? |` in ERE.

Comment: Now it looks like watching paint dry, not a nail...  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify things by using two distinct regex's ; one for matching the lines that need processing, and one for matching what must be modified.

You can try something like this:

```
$ sed '/^leaf/ s/-/_/' file
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf replace_these-hyphens
```

Comment: Neat! How does that even work? That first part is "don't match the characters `leaf`", if I'm not mistaken, but other than that?

Comment: For lines beginning with leaf, do the replacement.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Here, `^` is the "start of line" anchor, not a negation like in a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '$1=="leaf"{ sub(/-/,"_",$2) } 1' file
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf replace_these-hyphens
```

It gives you much more precise control over what you're matching (e.g. the above is doing a string instead of regexp comparison on "leaf" and so would work even if that string contained regexp metacharacters like `.` or `*`) and what you're replacing (e.g. the above only does the replacement in the text AFTER `leaf` and so would continue to work even if `leaf` itself contained `-`s):

```
$ cat file
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf-foo.*bar replace-these-hyphens
leaf-foobar dont-replace-these-hyphens
```

Correct output:

```
$ awk '$1=="leaf-foo.*bar"{ sub(/-/,"_",$2) } 1' file
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf-foo.*bar replace_these-hyphens
leaf-foobar dont-replace-these-hyphens
```

Wrong output:

```
$ sed '/^leaf-foo.*bar/ s/-/_/' file
dont-touch-these-hyphens
leaf_foo.*bar replace-these-hyphens
leaf_foobar dont-replace-these-hyphens
```

(note the "-" in leaf-foo being replaced by "_" in each of the last 2 lines, including the one that does not start with the string "leaf-foo.*bar").

That awk script will work as-is using any awk on any UNIX box.